# watchdog.hのコンパイルエラー

Tags: spresense, arduino

Watchdogライブラリを使用した際に，コンパイルエラーが発生するようになりました．
実際のエラーメッセージを以下に示します．

```
警告：ライブラリWatchdogはアーキテクチャavr, megaavr, teensyに対応したものであり、アーキテクチャspresenseで動作するこのボードとは互換性がないかもしれません。
```

コンパイルしたコードはオリジナルであるため，作成したコード自体に誤りがある可能性がありました．
そこで，Spresense Arduino board packageに含まれる"WatchdogTester.ino"というスケッチ例で試したところ，同様にコンパイルエラーが起こり，以下のエラーメッセージが出力されました．

```
警告：ライブラリWatchdogはアーキテクチャavr, megaavr, teensyに対応したものであり、アーキテクチャspresenseで動作するこのボードとは互換性がないかもしれません。
Arduino\libraries\Watchdog\src/Watchdog.h:37:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token
   37 | {
      | ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

これまでは問題なく使用できていたため，原因が全くわかりません．
現状，試したことはSPRESENSE本体の変更くらいです．

ご助言などいただければ幸いです．
よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 1):

SpresenseのWatchdogライブラリではなく、別のものをコンパイルしていませんか？

エラー内容から推測すると、
https://github.com/janelia-arduino/Watchdog
Arduino/libraries/Watchdog を使っている気がします。

Spresense Arduino board packageに含まれるWatchdogスケッチ例を動かすには、
Arduino IDEのメニューから、
[ファイル]->[スケッチ例]->[Spresense用のスケッチ例]->[Watchdog]->[Watchdog_bite]
と辿ったところにサンプルスケッチがあります。